# Magento: Can't run dataflow profiles: Ajax Error (Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

Whenever I want to run a dataflow profile in Magento, the following happend:

1. the csv file is successfully loaded
2. Found X rows
3. The following line appears:  Starting ... :: saveRow (handler-method)

But then an javascript-error occurs. For instance in Chrome Debugger you can see the details (starting from line 148):

```
function sendImportData(data) { 
   ...
   new Ajax.Request("http://www.magentoshop.com/index.php/admin/system_convert_profile/batchRun/", { ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
```

The used magento-version is 1.8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info.. We found the reason:
We used a minified version for prototype.js
We then changed this to the normal prototype-version and the ajax-request worked.